# Unpermitted Parameters adding new fields to Devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

when a user make a sign up and press sign up i get this error

```
undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fe4c2821988> Did you mean? fork

  }
elsif params[:action] == 'create'
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
    |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
  }
end
```

this is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [
       :first_name, :last_name, :address, :gender, :DOB, 
       :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
       :image, :thumb, :medium
    ]

    if params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
      }
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
      }
    end
  end
end
```

can i know what is the problem and how to solve it

Comment: what you want achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this problem, replace `for` with `permit` in your code.

**Explanation:**

The method `#for` on Devise::ParamsSanitizer has been removed in devise 4.2, and replaced with two new methods `#sanitize` and `#permit`.

`#permit` takes a block argument, so it is probably what you want to use here.

see:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.2.0/CHANGELOG.md#420---2016-07-01
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.2.0/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L108

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code for reference and change the `params` of your column name in user table that you want.i am using `username`
Add this in your `application_controller.rb`

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

###### PROTECTED METHODS #######################
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you have problem on signup time so permit params this way. also check Strong Parameters on device gem.

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, only: [:create], if: :devise_controller?

    protected
        def update_sanitized_params
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :gender, :DOB,:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:image, :thumb, :medium)}
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

well, actually i fixed it but the thing is when i go to console do User.last and i get nill

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
registration_params = [
   :first_name, :last_name, :address, :gender, :DOB, 
   :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
   :image, :thumb, :medium
]

if params[:action] == 'update'
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
    |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
  }
elsif params[:action] == 'create'
  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.fot(:sign_up).push(registration_params)
end
end
end
```

end

[image]

Comment: @Chaudhary Prakash can u check this please